# CORS issue confusion with AWS Lambda, DynamoDB, API Gateway and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

So I am building a contact form with ReactJs (frontend) and AWS Lambda(NodeJS), DynamoDB to store the data and API Gateway for the api to post to.

I have some confusion with my Lambda function, when I test in the AWS Lambda function it works fine when I cross check with the DynamoDB table the data shows fine, So to me its working fine.

Next, when I have created my API endpoint and tested in PostMan once again I get 200 OK and the data shows in the table.

But if I test on https://resttesttest.com/ I am getting an error regarding `Oh no! Javascript returned an HTTP 0 error. One common reason this might happen is that you requested a cross-domain resource from a server that did not include the appropriate CORS headers in the response. Better open up your Firebug...` Also this is the case as I get errors on the frontend with error:

`Access to fetch at 'https://bac1eal279.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev' from origin 'https://4aac7fcc99274cf38ccbeef575c7edc0.vfs.cloud9.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I am abit confused, any idea's might help.

**AWS Lambda Function/NodeJS**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: "eu-west-2"});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("Processing...");
    const params = {
        Item: {
            id: Date.now(),
            message: event.message,
            email: event.email
        },
        TableName: "primaryTable"
    };
    const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda function'),
  };

    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err){
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```

**React Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Contact extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    message: '',
    email: ''
    };
  }

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  /*global fetch */
    fetch('https://bac1eal279.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev',{
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      }).then(
        (response) => (response.json())
       ).then((response)=>{
      if (response.status === 'success'){
        alert("Message Sent."); 
        this.resetForm();
      }else if(response.status === 'fail'){
        alert("Message failed to send.");
      }
    });
  }

  onEmailChange(event) {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value});
  }

  onMessageChange(event) {
    this.setState({message: event.target.value});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container mt-5">
      <h3>Contact</h3>
      <form id="contact-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} method="POST">
    <div className="form-group mt-4">
        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" className="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)} />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
        <textarea className="form-control" rows="5" value={this.state.message} onChange={this.onMessageChange.bind(this)} />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

  export default Contact;
```

I have tried with Axios and its still the same issue? I have left the endpoint in so that the error can be viewed and diagnosed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postman uses curl and CORS is for browsers only. you will need to whitelist your domain in your api-gateway and lambda function.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that now in the api Gateway by enabling CORS

Comment: @Sole Nice to hear that it's working. make sure you dont allow all in your CORS. the best practices are to define specific domains that can access your api.